# Electron with react, how to get access to the main process that enable use of Context Bridge

Tags: reactjs, electron

Referring to this [article](https://blog.devgenius.io/how-to-build-and-publish-an-electron-app-with-react-tutorial-971e1d9d27ce) I am starting my journey with electron on react.
So I have electron setup with react and all I did was to run `yarn create react-app`,installed `electron and electron-builder` and update the scripts. I am trying to expose some system functions to show system information. This is my main electron file in the public directory of my react app.

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const path = require("path");
const url = require("url");

function createWindow() {
  const startUrl =
    process.env.ELECTRON_START_URL ||
    url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, "../index.html"),
      protocol: "file:",
      slashes: true,
    });
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 800,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "./preload.js"),
    },
  });
  win.loadURL(startUrl);
  app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
    if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
      app.quit();
    }
  });
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow);

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on("activate", () => {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

Also this is my preload file

```
const os = require("os");
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("electron", {
  homedir: () => os.homedir(),
  osversion: () => os.version(),
  arch: () => os.arch(),
});

window.ipcRenderer = ipcRenderer;
```

And this is how I render the data exposed

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const Main = () => {
  const { electron } = window;
  const { homedir, osversion, arch } = electron;
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        <p>We Made it</p>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="link1">Page 1</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="link2">Page 2</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="link3">Page 3</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div>
          <h3>System Information</h3>
          <p>
            The home directory is{" "}
            <span style={{ color: "#6645aa" }}>{homedir()}</span>
          </p>
          <p>
            The OS version is{" "}
            <span style={{ color: "#6645aa" }}>{osversion()}</span>
          </p>
          <p>
            The System achitecture is{" "}
            <span style={{ color: "#6645aa" }}>{arch()}</span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Outlet />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

The problem is `homedir`, `osversion` and `acrh` are found in the window object but context bridge is unable to run the functions to get the output.
I am told react cannot directly access the main process which in needed to carry out this operation. I am less knowledge on this and will appreciate some direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, on the configuration of your window, you disabled two security features: [`nodeIntegration`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security#2-do-not-enable-nodejs-integration-for-remote-content) and [`contextIsolation`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security#3-enable-context-isolation). There is no point in using a preload if you disable these features. Furthermore, if I'm not wrong, [`contextBridge`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/context-bridge) cannot work with `contextIsolation` disabled.

If you want to use the default recommended configuration, you should remove these options from `webPreferences` or set them to their default value:

```
contextIsolation: true,
nodeIntegration: false
```

Then, Electron also comes with another security feature named [sandboxing](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/sandbox), which is enabled by default since the version 20. With sandboxing, you can only require specific modules in your preload (emphasis mine):

> In order to allow renderer processes to communicate with the main process, preload scripts attached to sandboxed renderers will still have a polyfilled subset of Node.js APIs available. A `require` function similar to Node's `require` module is exposed, **but can only import a subset of Electron and Node's built-in modules**: [...]

If you want to use `os` and keep sandboxing, you have to `require` it on your main process and use the preload to communicate between your renderer and your main using [IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc). If for whatever reason you don't want to move everything on main, another possibility is to disable sandboxing, but don't forget that it is a security feature which **is [not recommended to disable](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security#4-enable-process-sandboxing)**:

```
const win = new BrowserWindow({
  // ...
  webPreferences: {
    sandbox: false,
    preload: path.join(__dirname, './preload.js')
  }
});
```

And finally, in you preload, you should remove:

```
window.ipcRenderer = ipcRenderer;
```

I can guess what you tried to do, but you should never directly expose the whole `ipcRenderer` API for [security reasons](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation#security-considerations). You can find plenty of good examples on how to use IPC correctly [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc).

---

If I can only give you an advice, instead of learning Electron using outdated articles, you should take a look at the docs. There are many good examples and all the info you need on it.