# Electron Preload file Disables 'Require' functionality with nodeIntegration set to false, is that correct?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm programming my first Electron application and trying to follow best security practices. I have a preload script that is attempting to load a local file required for a renderer page. I set nodeIntegration to false and contextIsolation to true. I thought those settings only disabled node.js functionality for the renderer pages and to use node functionality you were suppose to make an ipc call to send and request data via contextBridge from the preload. However with nodeIntegration disabled, I cannot seem to require anything other than 'electron'. I cannot even require('path') or require('fs') in the preload which is where i thought we were suppose to have that type of functionality. Is that functioning as you would expect and I'm misunderstanding something? Is it safe to leave nodeIntegration True so i can have this functionality?

This works with nodeIntegration : false

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
    loadIndexPage: () => ipcRenderer.send('load-index-page')
});
```

No other modules work(with nodeInt: false) however including

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
    loadIndexPage: () => ipcRenderer.send('load-index-page')
});
```

From here my preload fails because it cannot find module path or fs which is weird. Anywho thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electron with react, how to get access to the main process that enable use of Context Bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76608105/electron-with-react-how-to-get-access-to-the-main-process-that-enable-use-of-co)

Comment: That's literally the point of `nodeIntegration: false`, that the renderer cannot access any Node APIs, which `path` and `fs` clearly are. If you're interested in best practices, [there's an official document](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security) about that. Reading the official [security tutorial](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload) may also be worthwhile.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner the problem here is [sandboxing](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/sandbox), not `nodeIntegration`.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner the renderer yes. I thought the preload was the bridge between the renderer and the main to safely expose node.js. Which i guess if you can't access it via the preload, im confused as to the purpose of it?

Comment: Yes, I wasn't paying enough attention. @Arkellys is right, the "problem" here is process sandboxing. [Here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/sandbox#preload-scripts) is a list of all APIs the preload script can access when sandboxing is enabled.